# For a single server running cron jobs: EC2 or regular VPS hosting?

Tags: monitoring, amazon-ec2, linode

I'm trying to determine whether I should put this particular server on an EC2 small instance or keep it at Linode.  The server runs a variety of cronjob scripts that fetch data from feeds, store it in a local MySQL instance, and provide it to other services via a HTTP API.  Obviously the services that it exposes need to be available at all times.  I'm currently using a Linode VPS to do this.

I've calculated that it would be more cost effective to use an EC2 EBS-backed instance for this purpose but the prospect of a hardware failure taking down the instance while I'm away from my computer scares me.  Linode, for instance, would automatically restart my VPS after such a failure.  With EC2, what options are available to restart the instance automatically?  Is a VPS through a service like Linode a better fit for this use case?

Answer (score 0):

> the prospect of a hardware failure taking down the instance while I'm away from my computer scares me

We run many EC2 instances, but never had this is problem. Still, Amazon does **not** rule it out.

But given that it is so extremely rare, would some normal website monitoring not be sufficient? I mean, there are many things that can go wrong on a web server and this is just one of the possible (but rare) issues.